# Network access consent conflict with ATT request?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to release update for my application , but I've noticed there is a new popup consent is appearing at first time app launching ( attached image ) which is asking for network access via Wifi or Cellular Data.

[image]

Well, my problem is this popup is preventing **ATT** request to appear! , after I click on Allow the app is continue opening without showing **ATT** popup.

the **ATT** popup appears on second time when I launch the app , because I've already give my consent for network.

is it possible to track Network consent popup when user give his consent ? so I can show the **ATT** popup after!

Here is the code of the splash screen :

```
struct w_splash: View {
    
    let allTasksGroup       = DispatchGroup()
    @State var canCall:Bool = false
    @State var opacityAnim:CGFloat = 1
    @State var animationView:LottieAnimationView = LottieAnimationView()
    @State var active_window:main_windows! {
        didSet{
            allTasksGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    @State var lottiePlayed:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
       
        ZStack{
            
            Color(hex : "#641C9E")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
         
            VStack{
                
                Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width : UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.7)
                
                 ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.large)
                     .padding(.top , 20)
                
            } .padding(.bottom , UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.2)

            .onAppear(){
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
                    allTasksGroup.leave()
                })
                    
               
            }

            VStack{
                
              
                Spacer()

                
                VStack{
                    
                    Image("logoSuqare")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(height : UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.25)
                }.padding(.bottom , 50)
                
                Image("byNumbase")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width : UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.4 )

            }
            
        }
      
        .onAppear(){
            
            //Lottie group
            allTasksGroup.enter()
            //Check in or Settings
            allTasksGroup.enter()
            
            //fetch task
            fetchProducts {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.checkAndOpen()
                }
            }
            
            allTasksGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                canCall = true
            }
            
        }
        .onChange(of: canCall, perform: { (_) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                if self.active_window != nil
                {
                    Env.shared.active_window = self.active_window
                }
            }
            
        })
    }
    
    fileprivate func checkAndOpen(){
        
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {

                //ATT request
                ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        //Register for push notification
                        APP.shared.delegate.registerForPushNotification{
                            
                         check_maintenance {
                             
                            //if we have logged in user !
                            if !Env.shared.auth_token.isEmpty
                                {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                        
                                        Env.shared.api_checkin(forceRetry : true ){ success in
                                            
                                            if success {
                                                
                                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                    active_window = .landing
                                                }
                                                
                                            }else{
                                                
                                                checkAndOpen()
                                            }
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                }else{
                                
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                    Env.shared.api_settings(forceRetry : true ){ success in
                                        
                                        if success {
                                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                
                                                //Skipped!
                                                if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "skiped_subscribe") == true
                                                {
                                                    active_window = .landing
                                                }else{
                                                    active_window = .tutorial
                                                }
                                               
                                            }
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }//if
                            
                        }//check_maintenance
                            
                        }//End of push notification
                        
                    }//Dishptchqueue
                    
                })//End of ATT
            })
    }
```